# Customized decision tree splits and nodes using R

Tags: r, decision-tree

I want to generate a decision tree where i can use whatever splitting variable I want to use initially and after a particular node.I want to change the rules as well. Is there any package in R which can do this or does anyone know any open source software which can help me do this ?

Comment: Playing the devil's advocate here, have you already tried using a package like `randomForest` to see what results you can get?  I would wager that most of the time these packages already can give you a very good model without the fine grain tuning which you seem to have in mind.

Comment: Yes, I have tried randomForest .I need something similar to SAS in R wherein you can decide which variable to split on first and then nodewise you can decide which variable to use and then autogenerate the tree. Moreover, rules can also be visualised and changed on the go .